Errors reading csv file from different URLs
I cannot figure out why the same approach in pandas cannot be used to read the CSV file of the two following URLs.
import pandas as pd

url1 = "https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/a2dfa674-a173-45b3-9964-1e3d2130b40f/resource/07bc0e21-26b5-4152-b609-c1958cb7b227/download/testing_metrics_by_phu.csv"

url2 = "https://srhdpeuwpubsa.blob.core.windows.net/whdh/COVID/WHO-COVID-19-global-daily-data.csv"

df1 = pd.read_csv(url1) 
df2 = pd.read_csv(url2)

print(df1)
print(df2)


CSV files can be downloaded directly from the two URLs. The CSV file from URL2 can be read using pd.read_csv, but it is not possible for URL1.
Your explanation is highly appreciated!
Below is the errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    x =pd.read_csv(url1)
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1026, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 620, in _read    
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1620, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1880, in _make_engine
    self.handles = get_handle(
                   ~~~~~~~~~~^
        f,
        ^^
    ...<6 lines>...
        storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
    ^
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 728, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
        path_or_buf,
    ...<3 lines>...
        storage_options=storage_options,
    )
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 384, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
         ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Data Analysis\covid\covid19\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 289, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 189, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 495, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 604, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 533, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 466, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\huutr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 613, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden



What error do you get?

Have a look at the linked question (I closed yours). You can get the content of the page that way, and then you can use io.StringIO() and .read_csv() to get the DataFrame.
